Modularity from cubic reciprocity: does it generalize?
Background. Let $a$ be a cubefree integer, $N=3\prod_{p\mid a}p$ and
$$
a_p=\#\{\text{solutions to}\,\, x^3\equiv a\,\,(\text{mod}\,\, p)\}-1.
$$ Let $\zeta$ be a primitive cube root of unity and $A=\mathbb Z[\zeta]$. From cubic reciprocity we obtain a character $\chi : (A/NA)^\times\to \mathbb C^\times$ such that the multiplicative extension of $\chi$ to all of $A$ is trivial on $A^\times$ and on primes $p\nmid N$, while on elements $\pi$ of $A$ such that $\pi\overline\pi$ is a prime $p\nmid N$ it is trivial if and only if $d$ is a cube modulo $p$.
Define the following functions:
\begin{align*}
e(z)&=e^{2\pi i z},\\
\theta^u(\tau, N)&=\sum_{n\in A} e(N|u/N+n|^2\tau)\quad\text{for}\,\,\tau\in\mathbb H, u\in A/NA,\\
\theta_\chi(\tau)&=\frac 16\sum_{u\in A/NA}\chi(u)\theta^u(N\tau, N).
\end{align*}
Then $\theta_\chi\in \mathcal M_1(3N^2, \psi)$ where $\psi(d)=\chi(d)(d/3)$. That is, $\theta_\chi$ satisfies the usual holomorphicity conditions and for every $\gamma=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\in \Gamma_0(3N^2)$ the functional equation
$$
\theta_\chi(\gamma\tau)=\chi(d)(d/3)(c\tau+d)\theta_\chi(\tau)
$$
holds for all $\tau\in\mathbb H$. Furthermore,
$$
 a_p(\theta_\chi)=a_p.
$$
The proof of this can be found in section 4.11 (p. 155-161) of Diamond-Shurman "A first course in modular forms".
My question. If we instead consider $a_p=\#\{\text{solutions to}\,\, x^n\equiv a\,\,(\text{mod}\,\, p)\}$, maybe with some linear shift or some other mild modification, where $a$ is an integer free of $n$th powers (or maybe satisfying some other mild hypotheses) and $n>3$, does there exist a modular form $f$ with $a_p(f)=a_p$? Perhaps, there exist modular forms $f_1,\dots, f_k$, for some $k$ depending on $n$ and $a$, such that $a_p(f_1+\cdots+f_k)=a_p$? I'm basically interested in knowing if the $a_p$ are related to "modularity" in some way.
My attempt. For $n>4$ the argument of Diamond-Shurman requires serious modification, since then $A^\times$ will have infinitely many units, where $A=\mathbb Z[\zeta]$, $\zeta$ a primitive $n$th root of unity. For $n=4$, $A^\times$ is still finite. However, I think that using similar definitions for $\theta^u(\tau, N)$ and $\theta_\chi$ doesn't work, or at least I could not make it work.

Try thinking about this in terms of Galois representations. Where you have 2-dimensional representations of Galois groups it is reasonable to look for modular forms. If $N > 4$ then you will be seeing higher-dimensional representations, which might have a parametrisation by some more complicated automorphic object, but will not come from modular forms.

@DavidLoeffler I see, good point. I'm not well acquainted with Galois representations and their connection with automorphic objects yet, so this still sounds somewhat mysterious to me. But for n=4 it can still be possible, no? By "it" I mean the a_p being related to modular forms, and quartic reciprocity should play a role. The Galois group of x^4-a is D_4, which has only 1 and 2 dimensional irreducible representations.

It will work for $n = 4$ but the statement will be a little more fiddly. With cubes, either $a$ is a cube mod p or it isn't; but for squares there are 3 possibilities, $a$ can be a 4th power, a square but not a 4th power, or a non-square mod p. Try starting from the sentence "A weak form of Cubic Reciprocity is ..." at the bottom of p160 of Diamond & Shurman and working out the quartic analogue of that statement.
